# using regional indicator symbols for languages?

Tags: unicode, emoji

When designing a font, would it be appropriate to use [regional indicator symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol) to represent Languages?

For Example:
 +  for an [Esperanto Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would not be appropriate. Language codes and region codes are wildly different things – any correspondence between them is purely incidental and they don’t always match in obvious ways. For example, the country of Greece has code GR, but the Greek language has code EL.

Regional Indicator sequences as defined by the Unicode Standard only apply to region codes (as their name implies), in particular regions with a two-letter [Unicode region subtag](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/#unicode_region_subtag), which is based on [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2). See [Annex B](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Flags) of Unicode Technical Standard #51 for more information. Esperanto has no region code because it is not a region.

EO is currently an unassigned code – it does not belong to any region and thus may be assigned to a new entity at any moment. If you display “” as the Esperanto flag in your font, then anything written in your font will be compromised when a new country or territory is given the code EO in the future because you’ve been using the wrong flag for that code all the time.